# Where to place a helper/util function in Spring MVC architecture

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to know which is the best way to implement a helper function for unzip file in Spring architecture.

For example:

- I have the controller where I catch the request to unzip a specified file;
- In controller endpoint I make some checks about request and file requested;

And now, I want to know if is much better to have flow like:

1. MyController -> FileService -> FileServiceImpl -> unzipMethod();
2. MyController -> FileService -> FileServiceImpl -> FileUtils -> unzipMethod();
3. MyController -> FileUtils -> unzipMethod().

I'm not sure which of this is the best practice. Can you give me some advices? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the 2nd option because it will be good according to oops principles and will be independent and reusable.

You might want to have more business logic in future so it is good to have the service and service impl and also you might need the unzip functionality somewhere else in your project so it is good to keep it separately in a util file.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to Create a util class in `.utils` package and create a `static` method unzipMethod() inside that.

and then call from anywhere by using `className.methodName()`

Answer (score 0):

Make @Service class for your endpoint and in that service use FileUtils -> unzipMethod(). unzipMethod can be static.

Its good to have service class for your endpoint as in case of some conditional work or processing with unzip file your service can accommodate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a static method? Wouldn't it better to create a new class that will represent a file? This class can receive a path to the zip archive as a constructor parameter and then it can have a method to unzip the file. Class has a few advantages prior to static method: you can easily test it and you can easily mock it in unit tests.

P.S. You can find more info about "true OOP" [here](https://www.yegor256.com) and [here](https://t.me/yegor256t).